# realizing/ understanding $C^*(\phi_g(C([0,1])))$ and "support projection of an element of a $C^*$-algebra

Tags: c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

someone asked me the following question but I don't know the answer, but and I'm interested in it too. Let $C([0,1])=\{f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{C}; \text{f is continuous}\}$, $g\in C([0,1])$ be a positive function, $\phi_g:C([0,1])\to C([0,1]),\; f\mapsto gf$. Consider $C^*(\phi_g(C([0,1])))$ the $C^*$-algebra generated by $\phi_g(C([0,1]))$. How can you realize $C^*(\phi_g(C([0,1])))$? You can identify it with $C_0(X)$ (continuos functions vanishing at infinity), $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space. Is it possible to determine $X$, or is it possible to say what $C^*(\phi_g(C([0,1])))$ is exactly? 
Now let $\phi(1_{C([0,1])})=g$. What is meant by the "support projection of g", we write $1_H$? (because I read something like "the support projection of g can be expressed as $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(g+\frac{1}{n}\cdot 1_H)^{-1}g=1_H$ (this is a strong operator-topology limit). $1_H$ has to be an element in $B(H)$, where $H$ is a Hilbert space.. 
I would appreciate your help. I'm sorry if the question is wrong here, I'm not sure if it is a mathoverflow-level-question. Bye.

Comment: 1) Warning: your map $\phi_g$ is not a homomorphism. 2) You allow that $g$ takes the value $0$ at some places, don't you?

Comment: yes, $\phi_g$ is not multiplicative. Is it important that g takes the value 0 at some places?

Comment: No, but, as you see from my answer, the case where $g$ is invertible is not very interesting.

Comment: ah, I see it, thank you.

Comment: Btw, it is not ideal to put two rather unrelated questions into one post. You might consider posting your second question separately.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is concerned with the first question. The $C^\ast$-subalgebra $B$ you are considering is in fact a closed $^\ast$-ideal and hence given by
$$
\{f\in C[0,1]\mid f_C=0\}
$$
for some closed subset $C\subseteq [0,1]$.
Clearly all functions in $B$ vanish at $x$ when $g(x)=0$. Conversely, if $g(x)\neq 0$, then we have already found a function in $B$ that does not vanish at $x$. Hence
$$
B=\{f\in C[0,1]\mid f(x)=0\;\text{if}\;g(x)=0\}.
$$
Thus $B\cong C_0(X)$ where $X=\{x\in [0,1]\mid g(x)\neq 0\}$.

Comment: Hi. I have 2 questions. 1.Functions $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$ in $B$ could vanish at $x$ if $f(x)=0$ too, why is only the zero set of $g$ important? 2. I only know, that $B\cong C_0(\Gamma_B)$, where $\Gamma_B$ is the character space of $B$. Because you determine $B$ concretely, it is understandable that $B\cong C_0(X)$ with $X=\{x\in [0,1]:g(x)\neq 0\}.$ But how can I argue exactly, that $\Gamma_B$ can be identified with $X$?